# How to write a script for organizing my desktop windows? (WinXP)

Tags: winapi, vbscript, wsh

I would like to write a script that moves the currently open Windows to a certain location.

Ideally, my program would look like this:

```
var window = FindWindow("Winamp");
window.setPos(1140, 900, 160, 124); // set x, y, width and height

window = FindWindow("Windows Live Messenger");
window.setPos(1140, 0, 900, 124);

// etc...
```

I suspect that I need to use the [Windows Scripting Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host). I had a look at the documentation on MSDN, but I can't seem to find the API calls that I need.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

PS: It doesn't have to be a scripting language, C++ is fine as well.

Comment: What about something like AutoIT since it has so many super gui friendly options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx). Here's a CodeProject article that supposedly (I haven't looked carefully at the code) shows how to use it from vbscript: [Moving a borderless window - an alternate way](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/VBBorderless.aspx)

Also, an alternative to [FindWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) would be [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx), which can be useful if you don't have the exact information needed to use `FindWindows` and would instead want to get a list of all windows and your code could then select the most suitable window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something easy to code, you can use AutoIt, available here: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml. I have personaly not used it, but it seems to be able to achieve what you want, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). I have only used it for some very basic things myself. But I know it has pretty sophisticated [scripting abilities](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic21703.html).